# Page keeps reloading when I change iPad orientation from portrait to landscape

Tags: jquery, css, ipad, layout, portrait

I've been googling for days in search of a solution to my problem and had no success. So here I am asking for your help. Many thanks in advance.

The page can be seen [HERE](http://www.flymedia.ro/phg/znd/)!.

The header and sidebars have *position:fixed* in the style sheet while the value of left is dynamically generated with jQuery. For the header and sidebars to rearrange properly on window resize or zoom, I have added:

```
/* Reload page on window Resize */
jQuery(window).bind('resize',function(){
    window.location.href = window.location.href;
});
```

For situations when the window is partially occupied (like pressing [CTRL] + [B], to show bookmarks in Firefox, for instance), I've added:

```
/* Reload page if window Partially Occupied */
var screen_width = screen.width;
window.onresize = function(){
  if(window_width != screen_width) {
    location.replace(location.href);
  }    
}
```

Look at the entire code, I hope you will like it.

The PROBLEM:

On an iPad, when I change its orientation from portrait to landscape, the page will *continuously reload* (with the portrait orientation all is well). I don't think the iPad is broken because I tested on a second one.

Can anyone please tell me what the problem is? And if the same happens on a Galaxy Tab?

Thank you!

Comment: what is the point of reloading the page on resize? if you have code that arranges or positions elements on load, call that code on resize too. reloading the whole page for a resize is a waste of bandwidth and would be really annoying for the visitor

Comment: Why are you using both `jQuery(window).bind('resize', fn)` and `window.onresize`? You should only be using one.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but this did not solve the problem...

Comment: Why does it matter whether the window is partially occupied or the screen size is an abnormal dimension?  The css should just take care of it if it's responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem:

> On an iPad, when I change its orientation from portrait to landscape,
>   the page will continuously reload (with the portrait orientation all
>   is well). I don't think the iPad is broken because I tested on a
>   second one. Can anyone please tell me what the problem is? And if the
>   same happens on a Galaxy Tab?

The answer:

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange', function (e) {
    switch (window.orientation) {
        case 0:
            //portrait mode
            break;
        case 90:
            //turned to the right
            location.reload();
            break;
        case -90:
            //turned to the left
            location.reload();
            break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Reloading the page on resize looks like a bad practice, you may try using media queries to set a CSS change when the page resize.

to solve this issue, one thing you can try is to follow orientation-change event on iPads and ignore the resize event when the client is iPad.

I think you would need to add JQuery Mobile (JQM) for that. 
See JQM events on http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html